# How I can define spring generic beans using xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc

I have to do some unit test where I have to inject generic bean using @Autowired 
for exemple I have this bean and I want the some with xml configuration How I can do that should I have to use property to do this

```
@Bean
public EnqueteurRepository<Enqueteur, Integer> cache() {
return new EnqueteurRepository<Enqueteur, Integer>();
}
```

in my xml :

```
<bean id="enqueteurRepository" class="com.glsid.gnqst.repositories.GnqstRepository">
     <!-- What I should add here ?  -->
</bean>
```

Thank You for any helpe

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're wanting to use XML?

Comment: yes the unit test configuration was in xml and I want to keep this configuration if i can